# How to make it so a link to a photo is added to my file and automatically continues to work with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

If I copy and paste another image into this `div` with the same code. How do I set this program up so that I can insert any number of image files (coded as the one below) and it will automatically format it and continue working like the others?

This is the `div`:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
         <li><a href="images/blue_dress.jpg"><img id="girl" src="images/blue_dress_thumb.jpg" alt="girl wearing a blue dress"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var girl = document.getElementById('girl');
var image = document.getElementById('view');

girl.onmouseover = function (){
    image.src = "images/blue_dress.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Since new items don't automatically get event listeners, you need to figure out how the existing elements get the listeners and repeat that action on the new elements.

Comment: I'm... not... quite... sure... I follow you... But, are you adding the `<li>...</li>` with Javascript? If so, add the handler or whatnot there.

Comment: @Mary: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to add an  whenever the mouse hovers in your list item. Again, i am guessing this list item contains your image thumbnail

In your html add the event with the function to execute when mouse hovers over it. For instance.

```
     <li id="theImageArea"<img onmouseover="addLink()" src="file.jpeg" alt="this image" /></li>
```

In your JS file add the following

```
    function addLink()
    {
       var imageLink=$(document.createElement("a"));

       imageLink.src="someLink.php";

       imageLink.setAttribute("class", "someClass"); 

       $("theImageArea").appendChild(imageLink);
   }
```

Before doing the javascript part, you must include the `prototype.js` in the `head` section of your html which you can download for free.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I have reposted my code . . . I see you have jQuery, can we do this using simple javascript?

Comment: No, this is javascript. Its the `prototype` format. I have never used jQuery in my life so I can assure you this is purely javascript but with the prototype functions. The `$` stands for `document.getElementById`. But you must include the `prototyp.js` in order for this abv to come into effect.